# ASP.NET MVC 3 Ajax.BeginForm redirecting to new window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ajax.beginform

I'm trying to use an Ajax.BeginForm. When I submit, I want to render a partial view. Everything is working fine, but the InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace is not working, it opens the partial view in a new window.

I have also an Ajax.ActionLink in the same page, and that is working fine.

I have already added the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js and it still doesn't work. Also, in the web.config I have

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Here is my code from the view:

```
<div id="div_to_replace">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "div_to_replace" })){
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyObject object)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                updateModel(object)
                return PartialView("_MyPartilView", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return PartialView(object);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return PartialView(object);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an element on the page with "div_to_replace" as the ID? It's not in the code you provided. When I've used this in the past, I did not need the InsertionMode.Replace.

Comment: I have the element with the div_to_replace as the id... I will edit my post with this change.

Comment: Does the browser console show any errors?

Comment: No errors in the browser console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was using the last jquery version (1.9.1) and it doesn't work with the original jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js file.

I changed to jquery version 1.4.4 (the one that comes by default when you create an asp.net mvc 3 project) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have jQuery included.

Make sure you have a div with ID `div_to_replace`.

Make sure `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is active, on your web.config in `Views` folder

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have jquery included and Unobtrusive JavaScript Enabled = true.

Comment: In the same page I have an Ajax.ActionLink and it is working, but no luck with the Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: This is a section that I want to display to the user. Then he clicks the edit button and replace the div with the edition layout. Then I want to save the info, and hide the edition layout and show the info again. That is why everything is inside the div I want to replace after the ajax call.